# jquery show/hide html content when using checkbox

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show/hide html content using jquery ... here is the code:

HTML:

```
<table width="1077" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
        <td height="100%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="headerText">
            <h2>enter details below</h2>
        </td>
        <td width="17" rowspan="3" valign="top" id="headerText"></td>
        <td id="headerText">
            <h2 id="section"> test data</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="1" height="100%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="531" id="bodyText">more information</td>
        <td width="476" id="bodyText"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="150">&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                <tr>
                    <td width="7%" id="bodyText2">
                        <label for="zip2">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="check_medical2" id="check_medical2">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td width="93%">
                        <label for="textfield3"></label>
                        <label for="people3" id="bodyText">section 1</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="10" colspan="2" id="bodyText2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="bodyText2">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check_dental2" id="check_dental2">
                    </td>
                    <td id="bodyText">section 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="10" colspan="2" id="bodyText5"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="bodyText2">
                        <input name="check_life_insurance2" type="checkbox" id="check_life_insurance2">
                    </td>
                    <td id="bodyText">section 3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                <tr>
                    <td width="30%"></td>
                    <td width="43%">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="27%">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><s:submit value="submit" name="submit" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#check_life_insurance2').on("click", function () {
    if ($('#check_life_insurance2').prop("checked")) {
        $('#section').show();
    } else {
        $('#section').hide();
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hVWYg/).

can someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

when section 3 checkbox is checked .. test data should be displayed. but it is failing for some reason.

thanks for your help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hVWYg/

Comment: Check your error console. You've got a syntax error.

Comment: no error in the console

Comment: @user2180794, you mean... besides "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } "?

Comment: @user2180794 I highly recommend that you familiarize yourself with some developer tools such as the error console. You WILL absolutely save yourself time by investing some time right now and learning these tools. I say this out of experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this...

```
$('#check_life_insurance2').on("click", function() {

    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $('#section').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#section').hide();
    }

 });
```

Comment: FYI, this answer removed the erroneous `});` at the end of your code that was creating a syntax error which is why it works.

Comment: not exactly .. I was doing if($('check_life_insurance2').prop("checked")) and it was not working... instead of .. if($(this).prop("checked"))

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to control the visibility of one element based only on one check box you can do something like this:

```
$('#check_life_insurance2').on("click", function() {
    var checked  = $(this).prop("checked");
    var toToggle = $('#section');
    checked ? toToggle.hide() : toToggle.show();
});
```

I personally like to have selectors grouped together in the head of the function for easier maintainability.

Comment: I am looking to show different content on the right side .. based on which check box is clicked. little confused.

Comment: If that's the case, none of the solutions above apply.. You can replicate the on click event for each one of the checkboxes or if you want to keep a single function, the structure will be a bit more complex.

Comment: Btw, in my example above I'm assigning to the variable `checked` a boolean which tells if the checkbox is checked. Then, in the last LOC I'm using the ternary operator.

Comment: Might as well use `var` to properly scope the variables, no real need to create globals for this.

Comment: @Jasper that's right, thanks for pointing that out! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your JavaScript.  Running JSHint against your JSFiddle reveals an extra closing bracket, parenthesis, and semicolon '});'.  Remove this syntax error and you should see the 'test data' header show when the check-box is checked and hide when it is unchecked.  Additionally, since it seems as though you want the 'test data' hidden when the check-box is not checked you need to either hide it initially or check the corresponding box initially.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hVWYg/10/) of your code with the header initially hidden and the click function reworked to utilize the .toggle function and here are the relevant parts:

```
<h2 style="display:none" id="section"> test data</h2>


$('#check_life_insurance2').on("click", function () {
        $('#section').toggle($('#check_life_insurance2').prop("checked"));
});
```

Comment: thanks.it was a typo. I updated it.  Kylek's solution is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS like this:

```
$('#check_life_insurance2').on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $('#section').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#section').hide();
        }
    });
```

and if you want it to be hidden from the beginning use this on your CSS:

```
#section{
    display:none;
}
```

Here is the workin [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/L8Ych/)

Comment: display:none is not working for me. not sure why.

Comment: it is working.. caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this part

```
"<s:submit value="submit" name="submit" />"
```

It seems to be working now. Not sure but the namespace "s" may be conflicting here.

Here is the updated fiddle

jsfiddle.net/hVWYg/12/